# Jquery sortable and serialize to database

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

There are many posts on this topic but the have all confused me.

The items are saving to the database but I am not sure how to send it to the right row in the database.
I have a where statement that is WHERE songid = (the serialized id) but that is only copying each id column number into the sort column number. (did that make sense)

My db row fields are = songid userid songname sort

Each userid is unique and songid is set to auto increment. I want to have a separate order for each user's songs. Right now I am only getting

songid = 1, sort = 1;

songid = 2, sort = 2

and so on.

Not sure what to do. PLEEEEASE any advice.

the HTML

```
<div id="thesort"class="sortable">
<?php foreach ($query as $dataitem): ?>
<div class="row" id="theitem_<?=$dataitem['songid']?>" data-songid="<?=$dataitem['songid']?>" >
    <audio ontimeupdate='updateprogress<?=$dataitem['songid']?>()'id='<?=$dataitem['songid']?>'src='<?=base_url();?>/uploads/<?=$dataitem['songurl']?>'></audio>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick="playaudio('<?=$dataitem['songid']?>')">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></span>
        </button>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick="pauseaudio('<?=$dataitem['songid']?>')">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pause'></span>
        </button>
        <progress id='seekbar<?=$dataitem['songid']?>' class="progress-bar songprog"value='0' max='1'  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href='' download='<?=$dataitem['songurl']?>'><h3><?=$dataitem['songname']?></h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h5><?=$dataitem['songdesc']?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button id="item_<?=$dataitem['songid']?>" onClick="delSong('<?=$dataitem['songid']?>')"class="deletebut">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript

```
function thestop(){
    var serialized =  $(thesort).sortable('serialize',{key:'sort'});
    $.post('songshare/songpos',serialized);  
}
var thesort = $('.sortable');
   $(thesort).sortable({
    axis:'y',
    stop: thestop
});
```

The controller

```
function songpos(){
    $this->load->model('songshare/songmodel');
    $sort = $this->input->post('sort');
    $data = array(
        'sort'=>$sort,
    );
    $this->songmodel->Songpos($data);
}
```

The model

```
function Songpos($data){ 
foreach ($data as $dataitem){
//$this->db->where('songid', $dataitem);
//$this->db->update('songs', $data); 
    $this->db->update('songs', $data, array('songid' => $dataitem));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to save the sort order. You can make an array of the items:

```
var ids = new Array;
    $.each(inputs, function(i, pinput) {
        ids[i] = $(pinput).val();
    });
```

and update the table:

```
public function save_order() {
    $pids = $this->input->post('pids');
    $parr = array();
    foreach ($pids as $key => $value) {
        $parr[] = array('id' => $value, 'weight' => ($key + 1));
    }
    $result = $this->songmodel->update_batch($parr, 'id');
    if ($result) {
        echo TRUE;
    } else {
        echo FALSE;
    }
    exit;
}
```

I used a "weight" field to save sort order.